# New AutoML error: Object 'dummy' not found for argument: model_id

Tags: r, h2o, automl

When running H20's AutoML function I suddenly get this error, which I couldn't find anywhere else on the internet:

ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'dummy' not found for argument: model_id

I ran the same code before without problems, the error only occurred after I added features to my dataset (all features are numeric, data is confidential so can't post a working example).

```
aml <- h2o.automl(x = features, 
                  y = response,
                  training_frame = train_hf,
                  validation_frame = valid_hf,
                  balance_classes = TRUE,
                  max_runtime_secs = 60) # tried 3600 as well
```

Has anybody encountered this error before and resolved it?

---

**Full error message:**

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/dummy?dir=%2FUsers%2Fshiringlander%2FDocuments%2FGit%2Ftfs%2Fmodels%2Fdummy&force=FALSE)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object 'dummy' not found for argument: model_id"                  
 [2] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.getFromDKV(ModelsHandler.java:95)"                                                      
 [3] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.exportModel(ModelsHandler.java:219)"                                                    
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                    
 [5] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                                  
 [6] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                          
 [7] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"                                                               
 [8] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)"                                                                      
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:482)"                                                          
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:327)"                                                      
[11] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGet(RequestServer.java:251)"                                                          
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)"                                                   
[13] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                   
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                         
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)"                                     
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                             
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)"                                      
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                              
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                  
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                          
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                
[22] "    water.webserver.jetty8.Jetty8ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty8ServerAdapter.java:119)"                   
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                          
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                        
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                 
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                  
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)"                
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)"
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)"                                               
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)"                                          
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                         
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                   
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                               
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                
[36] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)" 

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'dummy' not found for argument: model_id
```

**R session info:**

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] h2o_3.23.0.4566

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2  tools_3.5.2     RCurl_1.95-4.11 yaml_2.2.0      knitr_1.21      jsonlite_1.6    xfun_0.4        bitops_1.0-6
```

Comment: Hi Shirin, are you able to replicate this problem on a public numeric dataset? e.g. https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv Can you also post the code that you used to add features (assuming you added the columns in R)?  Also can you try again on the latest stable: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html and also the latest nightly: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html to see if the problem occurs there too?  Thanks!

Comment: No, on the public datasets everything works as expected.

Comment: The code to add features comes from preprocessing and unfortunately can't be shared due to privacy concerns of the customer. But the structure of these features is not different to the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by specifiying what particular algos to use. You can check this: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/include_algos.html

This error is reproducible by using: `include_algos=c("StackedEnsemble"),` only.